# Why there is project size restriction for PhoneGap applications?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am curious to know as to why there is restriction on project size for PhoneGap application.
We can have project size up to 40MB.

This is as per [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_supported_platforms.md.html#Supported%20Platforms) of PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most they have said in public is that it's a technical limitation imposed by their internal design. They've been working on raising this limit for almost two years now. It used to be 10MB across the board.

I would suggest you just build locally.

Comment: It means building locally have no size restrictions?

Comment: Only the platform app limitations, which is something like 2GB on iPhone, 50MB for Android OTA applications (not counting expantion files), and so on.